# Como puedo calcular la distancia entre 2 puntos en Google Maps V3

Tags: java, android, google-maps-v3

Buenas Tardes.

Estoy utilizando el *Api de Google Maps* el cual debo de trazar desde cualquier ubicación y trazar una linea hasta mi geolocalización.

Esto ya lo he logrado ,pero el problema es que cuando realizo la calculación usando `SphericalUtilities.computerdistanceBetween O Location.distanceTo()` me da una cantidad que no se acerca a la distancia correcta o real.

**Por ejemplo: 1.2112E7 en ves de 1,200m**

**Código(DistanceTo):**

```
Location location = new Location("A");
                location.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
                location.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());


                Location locationb = new Location("B");
                locationb.setLatitude(latLng.latitude);
                locationb.setLongitude(latLng.longitude);

                location.distanceTo(locationb);
                String distancia = locationb.toString();
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, distancia, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Codigo(SphericalUtil):**

```
Double distancia = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(latLng,latLng);
            String distanciaC = distancia.toString();
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, distanciaC, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Se que lo que hace el código es que le da vuelta al mundo y obtiene una distancia mayor, pero no se como corregirlo

Answer (score 1):

Esto deberia ser algo asi :

```
    Location locationA = new Location("punto A");

    locationA.setLatitude(latA);
    locationA.setLongitude(lngA);

    Location locationB = new Location("punto B");

    locationB.setLatitude(latB);
    locationB.setLongitude(lngB);

    float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

**El valor que devuelve es en metros.**

Ahora puedes probar esta funcion en Kilometros  `CalculationByDistance`:

```
public double CalculationByDistance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
        int Radius = 6371;// radio de la tierra en  kilómetros
        double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
        double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
        double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
        double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
                + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
                * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
        double valueResult = Radius * c;
        double km = valueResult / 1;
        DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
        int kmInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
        double meter = valueResult % 1000;
        int meterInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
        Log.i("Radius Value", "" + valueResult + "   KM  " + kmInDec
                + " Meter   " + meterInDec);

        return Radius * c;
    }
```

Ten presente que en metros el numero sera mas grande.

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que si el marcador esta pero muy pero muy cerca de mi aun marca una distancia enorme. Además que si utilizo Google Maps si me da una distancia que es "correcta o real"

Comment: Estás seguro que el número que te devuelve es en metros ?

Comment: Ya lo corregí y utilice la funcion que escribiste y siempre me da 124mts a cualquier distancia

Comment: Añade el log para ver cómo se realiza tu proceso

Comment: 11-11 19:21:55.423 23739-23739/netolozanapps.examensegundoparcial I/Radius Value: 11124.804257203468   KM  11125 Meter   125
11-11 19:22:01.908 23739-23746/netolozanapps.examensegundoparcial W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.044ms
11-11 19:22:11.528 23739-23739/netolozanapps.examensegundoparcial I/Radius Value: 11124.233749957832   KM  11124 Meter   124

Comment: A lo mucho le atina a las distancias en otros continentes/países pero a lado de mi geolocalización, por mas cerca que este el punto b marca lo mismo

Comment: ¿hay alguna manera para calcular el tiempo estimado de una distancia a otra?

Answer (score 1):

Si usas el objeto `Location` tienes la función [distanceBetween](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]))

Su uso:

```
float[] results = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(pointA.latitude, pointA.longitude, pointB.latitude, pointB.longitude, results);
```

El resultado te lo devuelve en metros.

Extraido de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394366/find-distance-between-two-points-on-map-using-google-map-api-v2) no testeado...